# pytorch,opencv installation problem in python2 having cv library installed in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pytorch, ubuntu-18.04

haiii i am running python code in ubuntu 18.04

i needed opencv libarary for the code so i installed opencv using python3

```
 pip3 install opencv-python
```

but the code requires and compatible with python 2

so i tried to install the library using just pip instead of pip3

when i tried to install opencv using pip it is saying

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /home/sri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (4.4.0.46)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /home/sri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.19.4)
```

but running my file python train.py shows no module named cv2
some body please help me to solve this problem

same going with my pytorch library also

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "train.py", line 6, in <module>
   from model import CANNet
 File "/home/sri/Downloads/Context-Aware-Crowd-Counting-master/model.py", line 1, in <module>
import torch.nn as nn
ImportError: No module named torch.nn
```

so i tried installing pytorch

```
pip install torch==1.7.0+cpu torchvision==0.8.1+cpu torchaudio==0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html


 Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
 Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
 Requirement already satisfied: torch==1.7.0+cpu in /home/sri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.7.0+cpu)
 Requirement already satisfied: torchvision==0.8.1+cpu in /home/sri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.8.1+cpu)
Requirement already satisfied: torchaudio==0.7.0 in /home/sri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/sri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from torch==1.7.0+cpu) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: future in /home/sri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from torch==1.7.0+cpu) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/sri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from torch==1.7.0+cpu) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /home/sri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from torch==1.7.0+cpu) (3.7.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=4.1.1 in /home/sri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from torchvision==0.8.1+cpu) (8.0.1)
```

Comment: try to run you code with the command "python3 my_file.py" instead of "python my_file.py"

Comment: xrange is modified as range in python3 thats why ia m trying to run the file as python my_file.py

Comment: I think you need to convert your Python 2 code to Python 3 as it would be the best choice in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You are troubleshooting with your versions. You say your code is not workable for python3 so you tried to run it on python2. It seems that your pip is linking against your python 3.6 Version instead of python 2.X. The best way to handle these problems are virtual environments:

- Python 3.X: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html
- Python 2.X: https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Inside an activated Environment the command `python` and `pip` are linked to the version of the environment.